# Who are these people? Is that @jrg?

Tags: discussion, fun

Can it be that more than one Ask Ubuntu user can be in the same place at the same time?

Is this proof that people exist outside the internet?

[image]

Comment: Awesomeness all around in that picture!

Comment: Who are these strange people anyway? *I think I recognize jrg...*

Comment: Oooh ooh, I think I know!

Comment: Jrg, Flabricorn and... who?

Comment: @RolandiXor I'll give you a hint, i'm not the one taking the picture.

Comment: @mateo_salta: _Lowers voice._ Then who **did** take the picture...?

Comment: @NathanOsman All I know is there was someone else there *with a mac*...

Comment: @mateo_salta That's implying that *you* don't have a mac :P

Comment: I have a mac he has a mac, I brought my camera, he took the picture with it.

Comment: Can we get an official statement on this?

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ As the figure on the far left, I can testify that three people officially exist outside of the Internet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess jrg, Flabricorn and you... :D

Answer (score 12):

I do not exist outside of the internet and that is all I will say.

Comment: I don't believe you.